# Splunk query over @Timed annotation by the Prometheus metrics

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

As the title says I have @Timed annotation in my microservice written in spring-boot:

@Timed(value = "api.rest.get-account-msgs",histogram = true,percentiles = {0.5, 0.95, 0.99})

and I'm struggling to find the correct query for the splunk to visualize the results of this annotations, the query should show results of this method on daily basis.